# How to stop the music in the new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I put music in my MainActivity with toggle button. I want it stop when i go to the new activity, how to created the code to stop it? I can't understand about static/non-static message. This my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    MediaPlayer audioBackground;
    ToggleButton myToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        ImageView apin = findViewById(R.id.tombol_play);
         apin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PilihUser.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
       
        myToggle = findViewById(R.id.chkState);
        audioBackground = MediaPlayer.create(this, bgmusic);
        audioBackground.setLooping(true);
        audioBackground.setVolume(1,1);
        audioBackground.start();
    }
    
    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            audioBackground.setVolume(0, 0);
        } else {
            audioBackground.setVolume(1, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        audioBackground.stop();
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }

    public void tombolplay(View view) {
    }

}
```

Comment: _"I can't understand about static/non-static message"_ **What** message?

Comment: You can call audioBackground.stop() in the onStop method of the activity. Doing so  will stop the music when u put the app in background also

Comment: Yes you may just call the stop() method before calling startActivity(Intent). On a side note, I personally don't prefer how audio background is simply muted instead of turned off in your code. This means it is technically still consuming resources which I'd rather not have it do. But this is a personal preference.